# Верстка блока html

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как правильнее всего сверстать блок "выбрать пиццу" поверх других двух на картинке (или может и не 2 нужно - напишите лучший способ, пожалуйста)

Comment: .block {position: relative: top: -150px;}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например `transform: translateY(-NNpx)`:

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #ccc;
}


.content {
  max-width: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
  
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.7);
          box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.7);
  
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100px);
      -ms-transform: translateY(-100px);
       -o-transform: translateY(-100px);
          transform: translateY(-100px);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="top">
    <img src="http://www.wallpapersonview.com/wallpapers/2/fbcover_great_quality_facebook_timeline_cover_picture-588.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  
  <div class="content">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Или `margin-top: -NNpx`:

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #ccc;
}


.content {
  max-width: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.7);
          box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.7);
  
  margin-top: -100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="top">
    <img src="http://www.wallpapersonview.com/wallpapers/2/fbcover_great_quality_facebook_timeline_cover_picture-588.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  
  <div class="content">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Или + комментарий `.content {position: relative: top: -NNpx;}`

Answer (score 1):

Все просто: добавьте на фон картинку и прижмите ее по высоте наверх:

```css
.container {
  background: url('https://placeimg.com/1900/150/any') 50% 0 no-repeat #ccc;
  padding: 50px 0;
}

.container>div {
  min-height: 300px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class=container>
  <div></div>
</div>
```